# How to remove a string between certain slashes regex or excel

Tags: regex, excel, notepad++

I'm looking for a way to remove string after a 3rd and a 4th forward slash

E.g `http://www.website.com/content/remove-this/product`
to `http://www.website.com/content/product`

I can use notepad++, regex or excel

I tried using

```
/.*?/(.*?)/
```

but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Notepad++ with "Replace" and using expression

```
 ^(.*://)([^/]*/)([^/]*/)([^/]*/)(.*)$
```

and replace with

```
$1$2$3$5
```

Answer (score 1):

For the answers using Excel:

**Formula**

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),4)))&MID(A1,1+FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),5)),99)
```

**UDF** (using regex)

```
Option Explicit
Function Remove4th(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^((?:.*?/){4})[^/]*/"
    .MultiLine = True
    Remove4th = .Replace(S, "$1")
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do somehting like this:

```
<?php

$string = " http://www.website.com/content/remove-this/product";
preg_match_all('#http:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9-.]*)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)#ism',$string,$out);
$new_string = 'http://'.$out[1][0].'/'.$out[4][0];
echo $new_string;
// => http://www.website.com/content

?>
```